# Segmentation Fault with pointers arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a `Segmentation fault` according to my debugger but I don't know why.
Here is the code involved. Did I miss something ?

```
typedef struct Process Process;
struct Process {
    unsigned int m_id;
    unsigned int m_size;
    int m_startAddr;
};
```

---

```
    unsigned int** memory = calloc(MEMORY_SIZE, sizeof(unsigned int*));
    Process** processList = calloc(MEMORY_SIZE, sizeof(Process*));
    unsigned int itr;
    unsigned int nb_process = 0;
    int previous_process = -1;



    for(itr = 0; itr < MEMORY_SIZE; ++itr)
    {
      if(memory[itr] != NULL)
      {  
        previous_process = *memory[itr]; // works but risk of integer overflow
        processList[nb_process]->m_id = *memory[itr]; // segfault
        processList[nb_process]->m_size = 1;         
        processList[nb_process]->m_startAddr = itr;

        nb_process++;
     }

    }
 }
```

EDIT : I tried to make the following changes :

```
Process* processList = calloc(MEMORY_SIZE,sizeof(Process));
unsigned int** memory = calloc(MEMORY_SIZE, sizeof(unsigned int*));
unsigned int nb_process = 0;
int previous_process = -1;
unsigned int itr;
Process temp;


for(itr = 0; itr < MEMORY_SIZE; ++itr)
    {
        /* if memory unit is not occupied */
        if(memory[itr] != NULL)
        {
            /* if process is not known yet */
            if(*memory[itr] != previous_process)
            {
                previous_process = *memory[itr];
                printf("previous_process %u \n", previous_process);
                temp.m_id = *memory[itr];
                temp.m_size = 1;
                temp.m_startAddr = itr;

                processList[nb_process] = temp;

                nb_process++;

            }
            /* if the process is already known */
            else
            {
                printf("size %u \n", processList[nb_process].m_size);
                processList[nb_process].m_size++;
            }
        }
    }
```

The output of previous_process is correct. However, the output of size got a problem. First, it has always two values below what it should (14 instead of 16, 30 instead of 32; etc...) at the end of the for loop. Worse, the count start at 0, while it should start at 1, since i initialize temp.m_size with one before copying it into processList. So the copy doesn't work... Why ? Should i use memcpy ?

Comment: Don't dereference `NULL`? Of course, there's no requirement for `NULL` to be bitwise zero, so it's not even certain that `calloc()` will create `NULL`-pointers, but in practice that is probably what is happening.

Comment: Why do you use `**` ?

Comment: Checking for `memory[itr] != NULL` is obviously insufficient. You also need to check whether `processList[nb_process] != NULL`.

Comment: @EOF I forgot to write the condition where i check if memory[itr] is null or not, my bad. For Karoly Horvath, i use ** because i want arrays of pointers. The whole program depends on if those pointers are NULL or point to something during runtime.

Comment: The reason for seg fault is `*memory[itr]` is not initialised.  Accessing an uninitialised variable leads to undefined behavior, of which segmentation fault is one case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to John's answer above you are also allocating an array of pointers

```
Process** processList = calloc(MEMORY_SIZE, sizeof(Process*));
unsigned int nb_process = 0;
```

You must ensure that each of that array of pointers is initialized with something valid before de-referencing them as they are.

Answer (score 2):

You do this:

```
unsigned int** memory = calloc(MEMORY_SIZE, sizeof(unsigned int*));
*memory[0]
```

You allocated space for an array of pointers, but then you dereference those pointers.  But they are all zero (which on most systems is NULL, but in any case is not a valid pointer because it came from nowhere).  That can't work.

Comment: You might want to clarify the part where `calloc()` causes `NULL`, because that is not required by the standard.

Comment: @John Zwinck I forgot to write the condition where i check if memory[itr] is null or not, my bad.

Comment: The comments about de-referencing a NULL pointer are correct as are the comments pointing out that all zeros (the result of the `calloc`) in a pointer does not necessarily make it null.  Even if you are using a (rare) implementation where zeros is something other than null, it is never okay to directly assign a non-address-derived value to a pointer except when using a well-defined memory location (e.g. device driver) and then you would make such a pointer `volatile`.

Comment: @EOF: I have clarified that part.  Pedants rejoice!